# Pandas DataFrame slicing based on logical conditions?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have this dataframe called data:

```
       Subjects  Professor  StudentID
8     Chemistry       Jane        999
1     Chemistry       Jane       3455
0     Chemistry     Joseph       1234
2       History       Jane       3455
6       History      Smith        323
7       History      Smith        999
3   Mathematics        Doe      56767
10  Mathematics   Einstein       3455
5       Physics   Einstein       2834
9       Physics      Smith        323
4       Physics      Smith        999
```

I want to run this query "Professors with at least 2 classes with 2 or more of the same students". Desired Output

```
Smith: Physics, History, 323, 999
```

I am familiar with SQL and could have done this easily, but I am still beginner in Python. How to achieve this output in Python? Another line of thought is to convert this dataframe into SQL database and have a SQL interface through python to run queries. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2):

```
students_and_subjects = df.groupby(
                               ['Professor', 'Subjects']
                           ).StudentID.nunique().ge(2) \
                          .groupby(level='Professor').sum().ge(2)

df[df.Professor.map(students_and_subjects)]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you include the snippet to print the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

Solution with [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) and [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('Professor').filter(lambda x: (len(x.Subjects) > 1) & 
                                               ((x.StudentID.value_counts() > 1).sum() > 1))
print (df1)
  Subjects Professor  StudentID
6  History     Smith        323
7  History     Smith        999
9  Physics     Smith        323
4  Physics     Smith        999
```

and with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('Professor').filter(lambda x: (len(x.Subjects) > 1) & 
                                               (x.StudentID.duplicated().sum() > 1))
print (df1)
  Subjects Professor  StudentID
6  History     Smith        323
7  History     Smith        999
9  Physics     Smith        323
4  Physics     Smith        999
```

EDIT by comment:

You can return custom output from custom function and then remove `NaN` rows by [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
df.StudentID = df.StudentID.astype(str)

def f(x):
    if (len(x.Subjects) > 1) & (x.StudentID.duplicated().sum() > 1):
        return ', '.join((x.Subjects.unique().tolist() + x.StudentID.unique().tolist()))

df1 = df.groupby('Professor').apply(f).dropna()
df1 = df1.index.to_series() + ': ' + df1
print (df1)
Professor
Smith    Smith: History, Physics, 323, 999
dtype: object
```

Comment: hi, that does work, but is there a way I can display as per the desired format

Comment: Ouch, same problem as before, but please check my solution. Thank you.